# How to put dfsummary dataframe in pdf using R?

Tags: r, pdf, summarytools

when I write this in my chunk and I press the knit button

```
summary(bank)
data %>% group_by(data$y) %>% dfSummary() %>% view()
```

a window pops up with the 'dfsummary' data-frame outside of my pdf/html document. I want this data-frame to be in my pdf/html document. Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Can you provide any information on what you have tried so far?

Comment: See this tweet: https://twitter.com/DominicComtois/status/1344086619440238593 -- it explains how to include dfSummaries in pdf's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `%>% view()`:

````r
```{r setup, results='asis'}
library(magrittr)
library(summarytools)
library(dplyr)
summary(mtcars)
mtcars %>% group_by(mtcars$cyl) %>% dfSummary(, plain.ascii = FALSE, style = "grid", tmp.img.dir = "/tmp")
````

Result:

[image]

Comment: Right but it's not as pretty as the previous one with the view(). Do you know how to have the same please ? Thank you for your help

Comment: I edited my answer, if it solves your problem, mark the answer as solved.